# Login in terminal during installation

Tags: kubuntu, login

I'm attempting to install a custom kubuntu image (made by me using cubic) in VirtualBox but I get an error saying that the installer crashed. Now I wanna see the logs to get some clues about what could be wrong. When I open a terminal via Ctrl + Alt + F2 it asks for a user and password.

I tried using my own (recently created) user, and `ubuntu:`, `kubuntu:` that  I've found on forums, with no success.

How can I log in, or at least see the relevant log files about the installation?